# Can't get /api/login/ to work - JavaScript / Reddit

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, winjs, reddit

i'm running out of attempts... just got this "you are doing that too much. try again in 27 minutes." so I thought I would come here and ask.

---

This is the request I'm sending

**URL:**

```
http://www.reddit.com/api/login/
```

**Headers:**

```
User-Agent: "Reddit test app"
```

**POST DATA:**

```
user=USERNAME&passwd=PASSWORD&api_type=json
```

---

Putting the parameters in the URL instead... strangely works! I would like to avoid this though as it may not be safe to pass the password in the URL.

e.g. `http://www.reddit.com/api/login/?user=USERNAME&passwd=PASSWORD&api_type=json`

---

Another question... how do I access `/api/v1/me/` ?

Tried passing modhash as a GET/POST parameter, and also by passing "uh" as a Header. None of them work.

---

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use https://ssl.reddit.com for login. That makes the concern about passing parameters as part of the URL unnecessary.

Second, /api/v1/me/ can only be used with OAuth2 access that has the 'identity' scope. It cannot be accessed from a logged in session.

As to why your POST request isn't working, you probably have incorrectly encoded the POST data. Try POSTing your data to http://httpbin.org/post and see if you get the expected results back.

Comment: Not to mention that "hiding" passwords in POST data is not even remotely secure.

Answer (score 1):

i know its an old question, but just want to add an answer just in case some is referred here. I think the problem lies in not using the "content-type" in the header, as a result of which the post data is getting processed correctly. I was making the same mistake and a call ".setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");" fixed it. I think everyone is using frameworks like jQuery that must be doing this internally.